# need help for put a modal element in full screen over the fixed header

Tags: css, header, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, overflow

I have a big issue, i'm using a page builder to create four button with one modal per button. I want to display the modal in full screen over the FIXED header. Where i'm wrong?

Actual image: 
expectation image:

There is a link to the page if wanna see the css:

I've tried with z-index, overflow-y but nothing seems work. Thank you so much

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE].  Also please read: [Something on my website doesn't work, can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure that the header has a lower z-index than the modalbox, then make sure modalbox has display set to fixed `display: fixed;` with width/heigh of 100%.

Remember to set top/bottom to 0 if you want it to occupy full viewport.

Comment: Thank you for answer @San Jarral, the solution seems not working. Any idea?

Comment: it seems like you're doing something wrong, Please see the following image.
http://prntscr.com/m7jmoc
I only added the top/right/bottom/left + I increased the z-index of modalbox to be higher than the header and you can see the result is full viewport of the modalbox.

Comment: Ok, now seems work fine! Thank you so much for the perfect and clear examples :)